# What's the proper way to downgrade a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I recently installed the [Rails3.1-Devise-Rspec-Cucumber Starter App](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber) with the Gemfile listed below.  This created a Gemfile.lock file (relevant snippet below) that includes factory_girl 2.0.0rc3.  Unfortunately, this version of FactoryGirl is apparently [completely busted](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/156).

What's the proper way to force my bundle to use factory_girl 2.0.0.rc1 instead of 2.0.0rc3?

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "therubyracer", ">= 0.8.2"
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.1.beta1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.0.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.0.0", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.6.7", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 0.4.0", :group => :test
gem "devise", ">= 1.3.4"
```

Relevant snippet of Gemfile.lock

```
factory_girl (2.0.0.rc3)
factory_girl_rails (1.1.rc1)
  factory_girl (~> 2.0.0.rc)
  railties (>= 3.0.0)
```

Comment: have you tried running "bundle update" with the version of factory_girl that you DO want to use?

Comment: Ah, yes! Unintuitive (update to downgrade) and yet perfectly obvious at the same time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
gem "factory_girl", "2.0.0.rc1", :group => :test
```

in your gem file, and then run

```
bundle update factory_girl
```

Comment: Did you do a 'bundle update factory_girl' after making the changes to your Gemfile?

Comment: @chrispanda - Can you please modify your answer to include "and then run bundle update".  It will then be the complete answer, and I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: This may have some unwanted side effects. `bundle update` will update all gems, where as `budnle update factory_girl` will only update factory_girl and any relevant dependencies.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without editing the Gemfile?   In my particular case, I'm trying to build somebody else's project, and "bundle install" is installing a buggy version of a gem.